# select specific data from ienumerable<object>

Tags: c#, select, ienumerable

I am puzzled on how to get a specific info from an `IEnumerable<object>`.

My application back end provides an `IEnumerable<object>` which contains a collection of these two properties.

```
int id 
string chronik
```

for GUI usage I want to select the string property only

I tried this:

```
//creating objects
backend be = new backend();
chronikDTO cronDTO = new chronikDTO();
be.getallchronik(cronDTO); //calling DB-query via Entityframework
string[] cronarry = new string[] {};

for (int x=0; x <= cronDTO.chronik.count(); x++)
{
    cronarry[x] = cronDTO.chronik.select(y => y.cron.tostring());
}
```

but this doesn't lead to a usable result.  I've not written a new method which queries only the string property from the database, in case in other use cases I need both properties.

Comment: What is the type of `cronDTO.chronik`? And are these your *real* names? If so, I'd *strongly* advise you to start following normal .NET naming conventions.

Comment: Is this your actual code?

Comment: the cronDTO.chronik is from type IEnumerable<object> which inherhits from entity framework and this inherits from my database

Comment: so the code was one of my last tries ;)

Comment: I think cronDTO is a kitty, since it says "mew".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you *might* just be after something like:

```
List<string> data = cronDTO.chronik
                           .OfType<Foo>()
                           .Select(x => x.chronik)
                           .ToList();
```

(Where `Foo` is whatever your actual type is called.)

If every element is actually meant to be a `Foo`, you could use `Cast<Foo>()` instead of `OfType<Foo>()`.

Comment: nice idea. i'll check this suggestion. i sorry for the poor naming convention but i have got none better in the moment :/

Comment: thanks Jon you make my day.. seem i'have been running through a bunch of trees never seeing one of them.

Comment: @CalorHolderheck: Naming conventions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx